# error: non-aggregate type 'vector<string>' cannot be initialized with an initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I'm new to C++ and is trying to learn the concept of vector. However, when I run the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    vector<string> vs1 = {"a", "an", "the"};

    return 0;
}
```

The IDE output error message:

```
error: non-aggregate type 'vector<string>' cannot be initialized with an initializer list
    vector<string> vs1 = {"a", "an", "the"};
                   ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I thought the new C++ standard allow initialisation of a vector from a list of zero or more initial element values enclosed in curly braces. So why the error message?

P.s -- Using auto (which is also introduced in c++11) is fine on my NetBean IDE

Comment: What compiler (version) are you using?

Comment: Use `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14` compiler switch

Comment: You might need `#include <initializer_list>`

Comment: I compiled your code using OSX10.11.1 build version 15B42, and Ubuntu 15.10. It compiles fine. I used `-std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -pedantic -O3` flags

Comment: @Brian, no, `<vector>` is required to include that anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That error comes from the clang compiler, but only if you compile as C++98 / C++03, so that means you are not compiling as C++11.

> P.s -- Using auto (which is also introduced in c++11) is fine on my NetBean IDE

(Your IDE doesn't matter, it isn't what compiles the code, a compiler does).

Clang allows `auto` in C++98 mode, but gives a warning:

`prog.cc:8:5: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]`

So you need to

1. Enable C++11 mode
2. Stop ignoring warnings